# Functionality behind the contact us form which is built with site origin plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, contactus, siteorigin

I am new to wordpress and I create a contact form using site origin plugin.

[image]

When user filled his details in the contact form and click on CONTACT US button, then I want that the all the details of the user should be go to admin in the form of email, but I am tried to figure it out but I can't understand how all the functionality does-->

1.how to access form values using site origin plugin

2.process behind the mailing the user data to admin

3.how to access and store this form values

4.where all the files and data of the site origin are stored

5.And If I want edit or add something then in which template file I have to add that.

Please help to me Solve these.

Comment: Please note that you should only post one question per post. Otherwise the post will be closed by "need more focus"

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to post on the SiteOrigin forum: https://siteorigin.com/thread.

Documentation for the SiteOrigin Contact Form Widget: https://siteorigin.com/widgets-bundle/contact-form-widget/.

**1.how to access form values using site origin plugin**
Edit the page, edit the SiteOrigin Contact Form Widget. If the form is in a sidebar then edit the widget via Appearance > Widgets.

**2.process behind the mailing the user data to admin**
Edit the SiteOrigin Contact Form Widget. Enter the admin email address in the "To email address" field.

**3.how to access and store this form values**
Form entries aren't stored by the SiteOrigin Contact Form Widget. You can add a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-log/ to do so.

**4.where all the files and data of the site origin are stored**
In the WordPress plugin folder. Files shouldn't be edited here as they are overwritten during updates.

**5.And If I want edit or add something then in which template file I have to add that.**
Edit the page concerned. Edit the SiteOrigin Contact Form Widget. Make use of the fields provided.